# Convert Datetime format to varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have this code in my view in SQL Server to convert `datetime` to `varchar`.

```
convert(datetime, Product_Info.created_date, 101)
```

but I get this error

> Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.
>   Please correct the following errors and try again.
>
> SQL70569 :: A column name is required.

What's wrong? Please advice.

Comment: are you creating the view?, you might not have giving that column an alias

Comment: Yes, im creating a view

Comment: and did you gave that column an alias?

Comment: Try convert(datetime,[Product_Info.created_date],101)

Comment: I was wondering that even though I converted it to varchar but still the return data when I query it from controller, still a datetime format.

Answer (score 3):

Change `CONVERT(DATETIME` to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)`

For `MM/DD/YYYY` format (USA):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

Gets you '02/12/2016'

For `MMDDYYYY`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101), '/', '') AS [MMDDYYYY]
```

Gets you '02122016'

Comment: I am interested why someone downgrade my correct answer?

Comment: Because the all caps post caused you to become flagged by [smokey](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28729737#28729737)